# mysql fulltext returns zero results even though the exact search phrase exists in the table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table called `myatts` :

- It has about 3,332,834 rows of data.
- I generally search the column "content"
- I have about 40 rows where content = Rat, D.D.

However when I fulltext search for it I get no results. But if I use LIKE I do get the results.
I want to stick with fulltext, can anyone help me figure out why there are no results returned?

Here is my table structure:

```
id  
int(11) Not null AUTO_INCREMENT

join_id     
int(11) Not Null

webid
int(11) Not Null 

content
text utf8_general_ci
```

Here are my indexes

```
Keyname Type      Unique Packed      Field      Cardinality
PRIMARY BTREE     Yes    No      id             3332834     
content BTREE     No     No      content (333)  238059          
id_index    BTREE     No     No      webid      151492          
join_id BTREE     No     No      join_id        36          
content_ft  FULLTEXT  No     No      content        119029
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM myatts WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('Rat, D.D.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Here is the explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  myatts  fulltext    content_ft  content_ft  0       1   Using where
```

Any help/pointers would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minimum word length is probably set to 4. Check the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) for details..

Comment: ah yes, I thought about that but I think my brain was looking at the entire phrase as being more than 3 characters long. I bet that is it.

Comment: It will take me a little bit of time to change the setting to see if this is the problem or not. I gues I could also make a php script that checks the largest word in the search phrase and if it is less than 4, use "like" instead?

Comment: It kind of depends on if your searches are more natural language type searches or unique and specific (predictable) formats like model/part numbers. You can also fine tune which characters are stop words and how hyphens are treated. Reading that entire section of the manual on FULLTEXT searches will be well rewarded. Personally, I try to avoid the LIKE type searches at all costs unless I'm doing exact matches for part numbers or proper nouns (names, places).

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL's fulltext indexer ignores words that are fewer than 4 characters in length. In your my.cnf set this variable:

```
ft_min_word_len=3
```

I you probably don't want to go less than 3 because you'll end up with false positives.